# Rspec - undefined method `expectation_fulfilled?' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec, mocking

Basically I am trying to mock object here:

`if (object.present? && object.deleted_at.nil?)`

My model is

```
class Relation
  include Cequel::Record
  ...
  column :deleted_at, :timestamp
end
```

When I tried the canonical way:

```
object = Object.new
object....assign necessary fields
object.deleted_at = nil
object = double
```

Rspec throws:

```
Failure/Error: method_name.to_s if ExpectationChain === chains.last unless 
chains.last.expectation_fulfilled?

NoMethodError:
undefined method `expectation_fulfilled?' for nil:NilClass
```

When I tried the cheating way:

```
something = double
relation = double
expect(something).to receive(:nil).and_return(true)
expect(object).to receive(:present).and_return(true)
expect(object).to receive(:deleted_at).and_return(something)
```

Now `(object.present? && object.deleted_at.nil?)` evaluate to false

Huh? What should I do then?

EDIT: Tried the solution in the answer
`object = instance_double(Relation, :present? => true, :deleted_at => nil)`

I still get:

```
Failure/Error: method_name.to_s if ExpectationChain === chains.last unless chains.last.expectation_fulfilled?

 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `expectation_fulfilled?' for nil:NilClass
```

Answer (score 1):

With the "cheating" way you are doing two things wrong.

1) you are `expecting`, not `allowing`
2) you are `expecting` to receive `present` when you are calling `present?` (question mark at the end)

Can you please try:

```
object = double(Relation)
allow(object).to receive(:present?).and_return(true)
allow(object).to receive(:deleted_at).and_return(nil)
```

Then:

```
object.present? => true
object.deleted_at.nil? => true
```

There is also a shorthand:

```
object = instance_double(Relation, :present? => true, deleted_at => nil)
```

I prefer the second solution (instance double). Then, you cannot mock a method that is not implemented by `Relation`

Comment: Thanks. But the first solution gives the same error. The second solution seems promising, giving another error, can you help look at it?

    `Failure/Error: relation = instance_double(Relation, :present? => true, deleted_at => nil)`
     
    `NameError:`
      `undefined local variable or method 'deleted_at' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::RelationRequests:0x00007fecee311310>
    Did you mean?  delete`

Comment: Can you please update your question with: controllers/models of relation and object that you are trying to test?

Comment: the `deleted_at` not found was because I missed a colon. After adding the colon, it still gives the same error. I edited in the question.

Comment: @somenickname do not copy/paste the code, `ObjectClass` should be replaced by the name of the class you are testing (`Relation` in your case). Can you please check my updated answer?

Comment: I did know that i need to adapt your answer to my actual model. Sorry for being misleading, I will be more consistent in the future. You updated answer is exactly what I wrote then. And it still gave me that error

Comment: I have not noticed that you are using `Cequel::Record`. I am not familiar with that and probably I will not be able to help you. Sorry.